# Does it cost gas if a non view/pure function does not alter the blockchain?

Tags: solidity

Say I have a function which 'might' alter the state of the block chain depending on conditions.  Will I get charged gas if it does not?  For example:

```
if (conditionMet) {
  callContractWhichAltersBlockchain();
} else { 
  // do nothing, return false
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does, because the transaction still needs to be processed by miners.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways two call functions: local *calls* and *transactions*. Regardless of whether a function is marked with `view` or `pure` the gas cost depends on how you execute it.

If you use a local *call* there is no gas cost. You can even call regular state-changing functions but the state changes are only local and temporary (since the call is not relayed to the blockchain). This is useful for, for example, estimating gas usage.

If you use a *transaction* it will always cost gas since it's sent to the blockchain for verification.

You can read more about this for example here: https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Comment: Well, like you said, using `call` means that you don't pay gas regardless of whether or not the function is constant, and using `send` means that you do pay gas regardless of whether or not the function is constant. So in a way, the answer doesn't refer to the actual question (not implying it's a bad answer or anything).

Answer (score 0):

according to the solidity docs [gas consumption](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=gas%20consumption#gas) the line

```
if (conditionMet)
```

consumes gas,
and the line

```
callContractWhichAltersBlockchain();
```

also consumes gas when the condition is met,
and the line

```
// do nothing, return false
```

consumes gas when the condition is not met.
because one of the code blocks gets executed anyway.
so if you want your code to NOT TO consume gas when the condition is not passed, remove the `else` part.

```
function x() {
      [code]
      if (conditionMet) {
          callContractWhichAltersBlockchain();
      }
      [code]
}
```

Comment: You can implement an empty function with no `pure` or `view` on it. Executing it in a transaction will still cost gas, and there is no `if` there.

Comment: that's exactly true

Comment: You wrote "that's exactly true", and then extended your answer with the exact opposite (which is false of course)! Executing this function in a transaction will cost gas no matter what's written in it.

Comment: that's exactly true means there is no if, and else will be executed, because there is a code to execute when the condition is not met. that's exactly true, there is no if for execution of the code, it will be executed, and gas will be paid.

Comment: Like I said, gas will be paid for executing this function inside a transaction, **regardless** of the actual code in the function. So the part in your answer following "if you want your code to NOT TO consume gas" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @goodvibration i think either you are not understanding his question or me not understanding. i think he is asking about the gas consumption in the `else` part, not about the whole code!

Comment: Yup, it's you who is not understanding the question. The title of the question says it pretty clearly, and the body of the question says it as well. You've answer a different question - one with an obvious answer - of whether or not an `if` statement consumes gas. And then you extended your answer to yet another question with an obvious answer - of whether or not an empty code consumes gas.

Comment: i have to change my answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will cost gas, because the transaction needs to be processed by miners even if it doesn't change anything on the blockchain (in fact, that's the only way to determine whether or not it will change anything on the blockchain).

You can even implement `function func() public {}`, which the compiler will warn you that it can be restricted to `pure`, but executing it in a transaction will still cost gas.

Comment: The OP didn't specify whether he uses call or transaction, though

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: If he/she uses `call`, then `callContractWhichAltersBlockchain()` will take no effect, so I'm assuming that it is pointless. That said, one can use `call` in order to determine whether or not they should execute a transaction or avoid it. But in that case, one may simply split that function into two functions (a getter function for checking the condition, and another function for doing the actual job). Also, things "may change" in between those two calls. So in short, it makes very little sense to use `call` here, but your point is nevertheless valid to a certain extent.

Comment: Check my alternative answer and the link in it. Using local calls is valid for gas estimations, at least. Probably also for trying to figure out whether a similar transaction would succeed or fail.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: Yes, but again - risky business, since in between those calls, things may change. One could also claim that about `estimateGas` of course, but like I said - at least in this specific case, you may as well implement a getter function to tell you whether or not the condition is met.

Comment: Sure, there is nothing *certain* with this kind of things, just stuff that may help and are better than nothing. Implementing a separate function just for testing things is not very smart in my opinion - you can just do local dry-run call of the original functionality. Anyway, I believe we understand each other here.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: Yeah, I think I only discovered the `call` option for non-constant functions two years ago, when I ran into it while reading some Truffle test, and I was quite amazed that I hadn't been aware of it before. It is indeed useful in some cases.

Comment: These are all helpful comments.  I am triggering the smart contract function using 'call' in web3, and similarly triggering the downstream contract (within my own contract) using 'call' as well.  I assume I need to change it to a transaction on the client side, but I can continue using 'call' within the contract (if I want the transaction to alter the blockchain)?